# Use a for loop to create a series for a chart in excel

Tags: excel, vb.net, charts

I am writing a program to create a new excel book with a graph/chart. This chart will have multiple series (that will vary in number) with multiple graph types, but I am having a hard time using a for loop to create the series. Here is what I have so far:

```
        Dim Dataseries As Excel.Series = CType(chartPage.SeriesCollection(), Excel.Series)
        For index As Integer = 0 To GlobVars.filenameArr.Length
            Dataseries(index).Name = GlobVars.filenameArr(index)
        Next index
```

When I try to run this code I get the error:

> Excel.Series cannot be indexed because it has no default property

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like this

```
Dim ChartObject = CType(excelWorkSheet.ChartObjects("Diagramm 1"), ChartObject)
Dim Chart = calibrationChartObject.Chart    
Dim seriesCollection = CType(calibrationChart.SeriesCollection(), SeriesCollection)

' loop to create new series
For each fileName in GlobVars.filenameArr
    Dim testSerie As Excel.Series = seriesCollection.NewSeries()

    'Add values and customize the serie
    With testSerie
        .Values = New Double() {someValue, someValue}
        .XValues = New Double() {someValue, someValue}
        .Border.LineStyle = XlLineStyle.xlDot
        .Border.Color = Color.Red
        .MarkerStyle = XlMarkerStyle.xlMarkerStyleNone
        .Name = fileName
    End With
Next
```

Don't forget to release all references to excel objects after you are done or Excel will not close. Can't test it right now, but I think it should work.